How to preserve header content when converting MHTML files to PDF files using Java?
Below, I will briefly describe the problem:
First, I convert a DOC file to a MHTML file (Single webpage file) .
Second, I want to convert this MHTML file to a pdf file. But I find that the content of the header and the footer are lost in the new pdf file.
My code is as follows:
Document doc = new Document("XXX.mht");
doc.save("XXX1.pdf", SaveFormat.PDF);

The toolkit used is aspose.jar;
Does anyone know the reason? Thank you very much for your answer.
I found that the header in the mht file is written like this:
<div style=3D'mso-element:header' id=3Dh1>

<div style=3D'mso-element:para-border-div;border:none;border-bottom:solid w=
indowtext 1.0pt;
mso-border-bottom-alt:solid windowtext .75pt;padding:0cm 0cm 1.0pt 0cm'>

<p class=3DMsoHeader><span lang=3DEN-US>This is the header</span></p>

</div>

</div>

But when I convert it to a PDF file, this content is gone.
When I open a WORD file with Office, I can see the header content, but when I convert it to PDF using Aspose, I can't see it anymore.

May I ask why you take the detour via an MHTML file and not generate a PDF directly from the Word document?

Because I am currently using the Velocity template, I need to convert the WORD file to MHTML and then to PDF file. However, I have encountered an issue where the header and footer disappear. I would like to know if there is a solution. If it cannot be resolved, I may have to change the implementation method and convert from WORD to PDF.

I have tried the latest version of Aspose, but it still cannot solve the problem. Perhaps I can only change the method and directly convert from WORD to PDF.

MS Word and HTML/MHTML documents are quite different by their structure and it is impossible to provide 100% fidelity after conversion one to another. It is hard to meaningfully output headers and footers to HTML/MHTML because HTML is not paginated. If you are using Aspose.Words to convert DOC to MHTML, by default Aspose.Words exports only primary headers/footers of the document per section when saving to HTML/MHTML. So the only way to preserve the original DOC document formatting is direct conversion DOC to PDF.

Yes, just like you said, I cannot convert MHTML or HTML files to Word perfectly. There are always problems. Maybe the best way to solve this problem is to directly convert from WORD to PDF. Thank you for your detailed answer.

There is no way two applications are likely to produce the same output, for many reasons but focusing on this Question ONLY.
Take a minimal example of a Word.doc with headers and footers, then most "Word Processing" applications should have no problems.
Aspose WordDoc to PDF, handles the Headers and Footers well, if you do not use inferior double conversion which always doubles any problems. However there are many other differences in such conversion.
Documents dont have page number or sizes or fixed styles until output as another format. Aspose has problems maintaining the unknown size and presumes A4. Worse it seems unable to hold the font information correctly. So compare that with say cross platform LibreOffice which is about as close to Microsoft Office as it gets.
LibreOfice will also not be a perfect reproduction of MS Word doc output but is visually nearer.


I tried using LibreOffice to convert PDF, but the problem I encountered was that after converting WORD files to MHTML or HTML format, the header content would disappear when converting to PDF. It seems that using LibreOffice cannot solve this problem, but thank you very much for your patient answer. After converting to PDF, the font and other formatting effects of LibreOffice are much better, as you said, it is the winner.
